# How to upgrade Linux Monero to 0.10.3.1?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

What is the best way to update to the newest version of Monero on Linux?

I would like to do so without downloading the blockchain again or typing the private key in.

Also, I was curious how you find your current version of Monero through the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Whether you're on Linux or macOS, I personally think the most elegant way to install or upgrade the CLI software is using [this method](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2663/how-do-i-start-using-monero-with-the-command-line-tools/2668#2668), by storing the binaries in `/opt/monero`, as one would typically do with optional software outside the packaging system on UNIX-like systems.
2. Make sure to cleanly shut down the previous version of the `monerod` daemon, using just the `exit` parameter. See also [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/how-do-i-gracefully-stop-the-monerod-daemon-process). The blockchain LMDB database stays within `~/.bitmonero` and will be picked up by the new version where you left it with the old version. As an extra precaution prior to starting up the new version of the daemon, you could optionally either export the blockchain to a file (using `monero-blockchain-export`), or make a (recursive) copy of the `~/.bitmonero` folder. The latter will be faster to put it back in case something broke your blockchain …
3. When you add `--version` to either the `monero-wallet-cli` or `monerod` command, it will print the version, e.g.: `Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I ended up extracting the new tar and bringing over the wallet file to the new folder. Had no issues with getting the blockchain to sync, but will kept point #2 in mind.